# Run Jenkins job on AKS Pod

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, azure-aks, azure-container-service

I need to run my jenkins job on a pod that should be created at the time of run. I have the ACS plugin installed and configured. The test connection is working perfect. I have the Pod template also configured.  I am using JNLP launch method to create the Pod and i am not specifying the NODE - "DO NOT SPECIFY THE NODE".

I am using a freestyle project , where Office 365 Connector " Restrict where the project can be run " - Label Expression --> Container Image name 
Git Project 
Build : Execute shell - echo "Hello World"
When trying to run this . It goes in pending status and when checked the logs it goes in where a pod is created and destroyed automatically

Comment: please share more logs form the Jenkins plugin... this is definitely an issue with the plugin or the way it is configured. To help with this question, we will need more visibility into the version, the configurations, the template, the output, the error message, etc

Comment: also, your plugin quite old and has not received updates for almost 1 year. I would have a loot at https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-container-agents/ if I was you, maybe you will have mo luck.